# How to use terminal as program runner with FZF

Tags: zsh, rxvt, dmenu, fzf, rofi

I have a thought. Can I use a terminal as program runner?

Instead of dmenu / rofi I was thinking to list all the programs with FZF, run the selection, and then close the terminal after it runs.

I tried this but it's not working.

`termite -e run.sh` or `urxvt -e zsh -c run.sh`

`run.sh` consists of:

```bsh
#!/bin/zsh
preexe() { kill -9 $PPID }
exec $(whence -pm '*' | fzf) &!
```

Answer (score 1):

The `exec ... &!` starts `exec ...` in background and then exits.

You'd also want to decide where the command's stdin/stdout/stderr should go. You'd also want to detach the command from the terminal.

```
xterm -e zsh -c '
  set -o pipefail -o errexit
  print -rN -- $commands | fzf --read0 --print0 | IFS= read -rd "" cmd
  setsid -- "$cmd" <> /dev/null >&0 2>&0'
```

Here, we're running `$cmd` in a new session and with its I/O redirected from/to `/dev/null`. Ideally, you'd want to tell your window/session manager to start the command instead.